# Position relative to the visible part of its container

Tags: html, css

So in the example below, I would like the label to always be visible at the top of the visible red part even if we scroll vertically. Is this possible to do in css?

```css
.my_label {
 color:white
}
.event{
  height:200px;
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
 1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
    2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>
<div class="event">
    <div class="my_label">My Label</div>
    </div>
    1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
    2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>
    3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>
    4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>
```

Comment: In the example above, you have one extra `</div>`, please fix this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky`

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp#:%7E:text=An%20element%20with%20position%3A%20sticky,(like%20position%3Afixed).) but basically it will act as position relative until you scroll to it then it will act as position fixed and stick to the position you set it to until you scroll out of it

In this example I set it to stick to top of the screen by giving it `top: 0`

```css
.h-50{
  height: 50vh;
}
.h-100{
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg-red{
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-green{
  background-color: green;
}
.bg-pink{
  background-color: pink;
}

.normal{
  position: relative;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-50 normal bg-red">This will not stick</div>
<div class="h-100 sticky bg-green">This will stick</div>
<div class="h-100 normal  bg-pink">This will not stick</div>
```